# KElbowvisualizer Re-Formatting other Plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, k-means, yellowbrick

I randomly selected a number of clusters to plot my dataset with to see the distribution and then I went back and visualized the optimal # of clusters to use with my dataset by using KElbowvisualizer. However, when I went back to my original distribution to change the number of clusters, the formatting of the plot changed, a grid was added and the colors of the clusters also changed, which seems similar to the visualizer format. I made both of these plots in the same jupyter kernel but in separate cells. Is there something that is in the workspace that is interfering with the default matplotlib formatting? (Are the plots sharing the same axes?) I could definitely use a tutorial on matplotlib and plotting in the jupyter workspace.

Cell 1:

```
C = np.array(list(zip(ZX, ZY))).reshape(len(ZX), 2)

model = KMeans()
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(2,12))

visualizer.fit(C)    
visualizer.show()
```

[image: KELbowvisualizer]

Cell 2:

```
d = {'Myo':ZX,'Myo_Induced':ZY}
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=20).fit(d2)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

x = np.linspace(-5,5000,50)
y = np.linspace(-5,5000,50)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('symlog')
plt.yscale('symlog')
plt.xlabel('SJ_Myo')
plt.ylabel('SJ_Myo_Induced')
plt.scatter(d2['Myo'], d2['Myo_Induced'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5) 
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], c='red', s=50)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Cluster Distribution]

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the problem here is that the imported KElbowVisualizer changes the format of all plots but I could not find a way to turn it off while plotting, so it should only be imported for visualizing the k-elbow distribution and then turned off (not imported) after.

```
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer
```

Import KELbowVisualizer when using the elbow method,

```
#from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer
```

Don't import KElbowVisualizer when plotting for anything else.
[image: KMeans Dist w/o KElbowVisualizer]